# Como setar dados no localStorage

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$scope.loginUser = function (user) {
    console.log(user);
    $http.post("admin/php/login.php", user).then(function(response){

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage.setItem("chave", "valor - algum conteudo aqui");
            var valor = localStorage.getItem("chave");
            console.log(valor);
        } else {
            console.log("Desculpe, mas o navegador nao possui suporte a Web Storage.");
        }
        $window.localStorage.setItem("idUsuarios",idUsuarios);
        $window.localStorage.setItem("nome",nome);
        $window.localStorage.setItem("email",email);

        //console.log(response);
        $location.path('admin/views/painel');

    })
}
```

Como devo setar os dados para quem fiquem armazenadas em `localStorage`?

```
$window.localStorage.setItem("idUsuarios",?);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$email = $data->email;
$senha = $data->senha;

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND senha='$senha' ");

$return = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      $return = $row;
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Agora que eu fui ver, o angulares fornece um localStorage ? qual e a diferença dele para o default do javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

[`localStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) grava somente textos, sendo assim é necessário ter a informação em formato texto que pode ser obtido com o `JSON.stringify` caso necessário.

```
var test = ["Hello", "World", "Item 3", 5];

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {  

    //Gravando no localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("Teste", JSON.stringify(test));
    //

    //lendo do localStorage
    var itens = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Teste"));
    //

    for (var s of itens) {
      var node = document.createElement("LI");
      node.innerHTML = s;
      document.getElementById("result").appendChild(node);
    };
} else {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    node.innerHTML = "'localStorage' Não suportado";
    document.getElementById("result").appendChild(node);
}
```

Segue exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LAmorim/1c7xen50/)

Comment: localStorage é chave/valor, no valor e aceito apenas textos, caso haja a necessidade de inserir um array  sera necessário usar JSON.stringify, e interessante colocar esta informação como adicional para que ele não acabe utilizando ela em  textos que não são necessários

Comment: Mas onde eu uso o JSON.stringify? No caso, aqui, vc colocou os dados na mão "var test = ["Hello", "World", "Item 3", 5];", os meus dados estão vindo do php, do $http.post("admin/php/login.php", user).then(function(response), entende?

Comment: Entendi Leandro, estou fazendo isso:
$window.localStorage.setItem("idUsuarios", JSON.stringify({idUsuarios: response}));
porém, ao invés de salvar só o id, está salvando tudo que tem no response

Comment: ja tentou `$window.localStorage.setItem("idUsuarios", JSON.stringify({idUsuarios: response.id}));` ?

Comment: Descobri, usa-se, no angular:
$window.localStorage.setItem("idUsuarios", response.data.idUsuarios);

Answer (score 0):

Primeira coisa adicione uma condição para verificar se o navegador possui suporte, depois utilize o setItem() para inserir um item no localStorage, esta função aceita dois parâmetros, que são chave e valor.

Exemplo:

```js
var id = 1;
var nome = "Gabriel";
var email = "gabriel@gmail.com";
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  localStorage.setItem("id", id);
  localStorage.setItem("nome", nome);
  localStorage.setItem("email", email);
  print("id");
  print("nome");
  print("email");
} else {
  console.log("Desculpe, mas o navegador nao possui suporte a Web Storage.");
}

function print(key) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += localStorage.getItem(key) + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v13wzmbw/)

Comment: Já coloquei a verificação...
Mas que valor, conteúdo eu coloco em "valor - algum conteudo aqui"?

Comment: Como eu indico que quero colocar o id, no primeiro, nome, no segundo e email no terceiro?

Comment: onde esta "valor - algum conteudo aqui" voce coloca o seu valor/ variável etc... na chave a identificação por que quando voce fizer um getItem("chave") voce ira receber o valor que colocou, cole isto no jsfiddle e veja o console

Comment: Mas eu estou, primeiramente, pegando os dados do backend em php que esta sendo retornado, para colocar, pela primeira vez, em localStorage, entende? E não pegar os dados que já estão local.

Comment: Voce usa ajax para pegar os dados do backend? o backend e em php ?

Comment: No código que vc postou, vc coloca "na mão" os dados na variável... Mas eu quero que o sistema sete os valores da variável, saca?

Comment: e como voce pega os valores do sistema ?

Comment: Não, não estou usando ajax. E sim, estou usando php... Vou postar meu código em php.